# Subtract month from date column

Tags: date, amazon-redshift, intervals

I would like to subtract one month from a date column in Amazon Redshift (a fork of PostgreSQL 8.0.2).

So for each date column in a table, it will add another column date_minus_a_month.

I tried this code

```
Select date,date::date -interval '1 month'
from table
```

and received  an  error:

> Interval values with month or year parts are not supported.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What is the type of the `date` column in your table?

Comment: Missing `v` ==> use `interval` but not `interal` word. Also use `interval '1' month` but not `interal '1 month'`

Comment: What database server are you using? I guess this is not a *pure* Postgres but a derived database.

Comment: solved by add_month redshift function

Answer (score 4):

You can use `datesub`, although I just use `dateadd` for everything and use negative numbers.

eg

```
SELECT getdate() as right_now, dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) as last_month
```

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html